# How to access FitNesse defined variable in fixture code in .Net

Tags: .net, variables, fitnesse

This seems like it's too easy but I'm pulling my hair out trying to find where it's documented!

I've defined a variable in my FitNesse root page, e.g.

```
!define foo {bar}
```

Now I simply want to access the value of the foo variable **in C# fixture code**.

All the examples show how to access the variable on a wiki page, not how to do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

The intent of variables is to provide a way to pass data into a fixture.  I know in Java that the fixtures do not have access to variables and their contents.  I believe the same to be true in FitSharp.

You should ensure that the variable is an input into your fixture.

```
!define foo {foobar}
!define bar {bingo}

|simple fixture|
|name|length?|
|${foo}|6|
|${bar}|5|
```

The thing to understand about variables and how they work is that they are rendered in the context of the page.  So the value in foo is being sent into the fixture, not a reference to foo.

On the other hand, you can reference Symbols, but they work differently.  Symbols are assigned values at test run time rather than at page render time.  You can see more about Symbols in FitSharp here: http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/SymbolValues.html

Comment: Thanks, I know how to access variable values in page markup, as I said. What I want, however, is to access variables in the code. For example, I'd like to be able to set a flag to determine whether to use an embedded DB and access that in my code when the DB connection is initialised. If that's not possible, how would you do that without using a fixture?

Comment: You could always have your fixtures share a singleton that stores the connection data and have one fixture just do the configuration using the variables.

Comment: The reason fixtures can't access wiki variables is because fixtures work with HTML that is generated from the wiki pages, not with the original wiki pages. By the time the fixtures are created, the wiki variables have been rendered into the HTML pages and are gone.  FitNesse is basically a mash-up of the original Fit, which used hand-written HTML, and the wiki, which creates HTML from a wiki language.